# What is the intersection of two languages?

Tags: union, intersection, formal-languages, automaton

Given the languages

```
L1={anb2m|n,m≥1}
L2={anb3n|n≥0}

L = L1 ∩ L2
```

I know that `L1` is regular language and `L2` can be represented by a PDA.

But I don't understand the answer which states that `L` is `{a2nb6n|n≥1}`. How was this solution computed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the intersection of two languages with different alphabets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213955/what-is-the-intersection-of-two-languages-with-different-alphabets)

Comment: @rici that is exaclty what i don't understand about it, `L` is basically the solution provided

Comment: @totoro: OK, I tried to edit your question to make it clearer what your point of confusion was. Questions like this really should be asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/, since they really have nothing to do with programming. However, be aware that your question will not be well-received there unless you make some attempt to show your work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A language is just a set (of valid strings), so what we have here is really just a simple problem in integer arithmetic. It's only necessary to remove the elegant costume of formal languages to arrive at the essence of the problem.

Both sets `L1` and `L2` are subsets of `{acount(a)bcount(b)|j,k≥0}`; that is, they consist of some number of <kbd>a</kbd>s followed by some number of <kbd>b</kbd>s. The condition for `L1` restricts `count(b)` to be a positive even number, since it must be `2m` for some integer `m≥1`. The condition for `L2` restricts `count(b)` to be exactly `3×count(a)`.

Now, the intersection of two sets defined with predicates is the set of elements such that both predicates are true. So `count(b)` must be both divisible by 2 and by 3, which means that it must be divisible by 6; in other words, it must be `6n` for some positive integer `n`. And that means that `count(a)` must be `2n` since there are exactly three times as many <kbd>b</kbd>s. That gives you the provided answer.

Like `L2`, `L` is not regular, but it can be implemented with a very similar PDA.